# Python: AttributeError module x has no attribute y

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, python-module, pipenv

I have a project with directory structure like below

```
.
├── Pipfile
├── Pipfile.lock
├── module
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── helpers
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── __pycache__
│   │   │   └── __init__.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   ├── dynamo.py
│   │   └── logger.py
│   └── test.py
```

Relavant code

> logger.py

```
import click
import sys
from tabulate import tabulate


def formatter(string, *rest):
    return string.format(*rest)


def info(*rest):
    """Write text in blue color
    """
    click.echo(click.style('☵ ' + formatter(*rest), fg='blue'))
```

> test.py

```
import helpers

helpers.logger.info('Trying')
```

When I try to run using the command

```
python3 module/test.py
```

I get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "module/test.py", line 4, in <module>
    helpers.logger.info('Trying')
AttributeError: module 'helpers' has no attribute 'logger'
```

I have tried restructuring the code. Putting the `helpers` directory outside, in level with `module` directory. But still it didn't work, which it should not have, from what I have read. I tried researching a bit about `__init__.py` and python module system. The more I read, the more confusing it gets. But from whatever I learned, I created another sample project. With the following structure,

```
.
└── test
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── helpers
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── __pycache__
    │   │   ├── __init__.cpython-36.pyc
    │   │   └── quote.cpython-36.pyc
    │   └── quote.py
    ├── index.py
    ├── logger
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── __pycache__
    │   │   ├── __init__.cpython-36.pyc
    │   │   └── info.cpython-36.pyc
    │   └── info.py
```

Code is same as first project.

Here when I do,

```
python3 test/index.py
```

It works as expected. The only difference between the two projects:

> In the first project, I used `pipenv` to install deps and create virtual environment.

Comment: That is not how Python package imports work. If you want to use `logger`, you need to import it explicitly; best way is to use `from helpers import logger` and then `logger.info(...)`. However, you should also consider not doing any of this but using the `logging` module from the stdlib.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`logger` is module and not attribute and `helpers.logger` evalutes `logger` as attribute. Actually you should do as follow:

```
from helpers import logger

print(logger.info('Trying'))
```

Answer (score 8):

Using your initial layout (with `loggers` as a submodule of the `helpers` package), you'd need to explicitely import `loggers` in `helpers/__init__.py` to expose it as an attribute of the `helpers` package:

```
# helpers/__init__.py
from . import logger
```

Comment: After numerous stackoverflow searches, this was the answer i was looking for - thank you!

Comment: As a newcomer to python this was very helpful